# ConEmu - How to create 3 Vertical & 1 Horizontal split?

Tags: conemu

How to create the below splits in ConEmu?

[image: ConEmu Layout]

I tried the below commands and it did not help.

cmd -cur_console:n
powershell -cur_console:s1TVn
bash -l -i -cur_console:s1THn
cmd -cur_console:s2THn

Comment: The below commands is actually "one command". What exactly have you tried add what was the result? Also, I the command I see PowerShell, bash and cmd. They obviously doesn't match your picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy. Just use [new console dialog](https://conemu.github.io/en/LaunchNewTab.html#Create_new_console_dialog).

- Start one cmd pane
- Start new PowerShell pane to the right
- Activate first pane and start new cmd panes to the bottom (twice).

Done. You may go to the [Tasks](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsTasks.html#id2493) page and add "Active tabs" to new task.

Comment: Thaks a lot. This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to create three `Cmd` shells on the *left* and one `Powershell` on the *right*.

### Step `1` :

Start `conemu64` with `cmd`:

Press `Win` + `R` which will open run dialog box and then type `conemu64 "cmd"` in it and press enter this will launch Conemu64 with cmd.

[image: Run Dialog Box in Windows]

---

### Step `2` :

Type `pwsh -new_console:s` in `conemu64` and this will create a horizontal split with `pwsh shell` on the right side

[image: Split horizontally]

---

### Step `3` :

Now focus is on the right shell come to the left panel press `Ctrl` + `Tab` or by clicking on the left panel.

---

### Step `4` :

In the left terminal execute this command `cmd -new_console:s66V` which will create a new shell with **66%** of height because if we have **3** shells each will take **33.33%** of height that's why we are allocating **66%** of height to the second shell which we will further split into *two* shells.

[image: new shell]

---

### Step `5` :

Now lets create a vertical split. In order to create a vertical split type `cmd -new_console:sV` in the previous newly created shell. By default it will take **50%** of the parent shell's height so no need to specify height in this case.

[image: new shell]